# How to create boxplot of logical and numerical value in r?

Tags: r, boxplot

I have a trivial question that I can't seem to figure out. I have a data matrix of dimension 20000 X 1. I have another logical variable called logVal of the length 20000. The logical value pertains to whether the matrix elements falls below certain value or not. If it does, the logVal is TRUE, or else it's FALSE. I want to make a boxplot to whether the logVal behaves differently for the matrix. But i can't seem to figure out how to do this. Can somebody please help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this?

```
df <- data.frame(v <- runif(20000, 0, 1))
df$g <- ifelse(df$v < 0.5, T, F)
with(df, boxplot(v~g))
```

[image: boxplot]

Comment: Thank @Paulo Cardoso. I think that's what I'm looking for. Lol. I'll mark it as an answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @user1828605 If you provide more detail we can adjust this to your needs. It's relatively simple as you can see.